To cluster data of this form into optimum buckets of <3 hours based on time difference
graphical representation of data
My data is of the following type: time_start to time_end. I need to group them into buckets of at most 3 hours, based on the time diff between any two entries given as min (diff between their start times, diff between their end times, diff between start and end time); I also have to account for entries that are overlapping and fall within another entry. I do not just want to start an interval from the start time and change to a different interval when 3 hours have elapsed. For instance, it makes more sense to club a 10:45-11:30 entry with a 12-12:30 entry (0.5 hour time lag) as opposed to an 8-8:30 entry (2h 15 minute time lag.)
I'm running into issues in cases like:
Example data: (The first column represents the ids of the time durations; I need to cluster these ids optimally.)
`'1',    '08:00', '10:00'
'2',    '09:00', '09:15'
'3',    '09:00', '09:30'
'4',    '09:00', '11:00'
'5',    '10:00', '10:15'
'6',    '10:00', '10:45'
'7',    '10:15', '10:30'
'8',    '11:00', '11:45'
'9',    '12:00', '12:15'`
How do I divide the clusters here?
For clustering, can I use any of the standard methods like k-means after converting time intervals into decimal format (fraction of a day.)
